# Facebook.com endpoint url

Tags: python

I have been writing a program to login to facebook in python and I know from reading other forums that the endpoint url is https://facebook.com/login.php. However, when I monitor my own login in the network tab, it seems the request url is https://facebook.com/login/device-based/regular/login, but it doesn’t work when I send a post request in my code. Only login.php does. My question is how would I be able to know that from looking at the requests?

Comment: Don't use the human login portal to write scripts for Facebook. They have an API for that sort of thing. You'll probably just get captcha'd anyway

Comment: Ok but my point is why doesn't facebook work the same way as twitter or linkedin in terms of the URL. This is really for educational purposes and facebook is just an example that I found to be different than other sites